# Marionette way to Live form validation

Tags: forms, validation, marionette

What is that Marionette way to live (i.e. on every key press) form validation? I mean both two cases - on client-side and - at rare case - via ajax with deffereds.

We already have model's validation. So, the situation has Backbone/Marionette specifics, if we want to use model's validation for client-side live form validation also.

Answer (score 0):

You can use server side validation.
The server should return error code 422 with a Json similar like:

```
{"errors":{"user_email":["can't be blank"]}}
```

Then on client side use backbone's error callback (my code is in coffee script.):

```
  @model.save null,
    update: on
    success: => @afterSuccessfullSave()
    error:  @setErrors
```

The @setErrors method callback then adds error specific classes to the labels and inputs.

Or there is a gem for Ruby https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations there the **model** branch is intended to satisfy out bacbone needs but is not maintained... soo... I can advise you the server side validation or to write your own custom validation rule serializations...

Comment: Sorry, in this question I'm interested in client-side with "as you type" reaction. In this context server-side isn't more rather sometimes to say "such user already exists" or something similar. Of course, server-side validation takes place at any case, but it is another bit of swing.

Comment: In case if you don't want to duplicate the server side validation code then you need to find a way to serialize the server side rules to javascript. In case if you are working with RoR then one solution for this is to fork the above mentioned gem in the model branch then you almost have a working solution.

Comment: There is a http://lab.narf.pl/jquery-typing/ plugin which can be instanciated in the onRender method of any view. And on the stop callback you can trigger your own client side validation routines.